# SSHing to raspberry pi returns "middle man attack"

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I am trying to SSH to my raspberry pi which is connected under the same router as my computer. It is running the latest version of raspbian lite. I enabled the ssh service on the pi using the command: `systemctl enable ssh`. However when I try to SSH to my raspberrypi from my personal computer, I get this message:

```sh
fahd@Fahd-PC:~$ ssh pi@192.168.1.23
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:***************************************************
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/fahd/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/fahd/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/fahd/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "192.168.1.23"
ECDSA host key for 192.168.1.23 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fahd@Fahd-PC:~$
```

And I'm not entirely sure whether this is something real I should be worried about or just me not knowing how to use SSH properly.

Comment: Have you recently reinstalled the OS? Is this a new Pi? Any other computers used on the network occasionally?

Comment: It is most likely safe, it's just that you have previously connected to a different computer that had previously been assigned that IP by your router.

Comment: Yes I have recently reinstalled the OS on the pi. It is the same old pi though. My parents are connected to the router and a few phones but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, your terminal has a different key in storage for your Pi. This can be due to several reasons (for example, the ssh package was updated and the SSH host key re-generated on the Pi. Or you changed the IPs on your network. Or you have DHCP and *two* different clients, and you got the addresses swapped. Or...).

So, it warns you.

Unless you have reasons to believe otherwise, I'd just follow the suggestion:

remove with:
ssh-keygen -f "/home/fahd/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "192.168.1.23"

Answer (score 0):

This communicates inform you that RSA keys on the device has changed it happen when you:

- reinstall OS on device
- generate new / remove old RSA keys
- someone is trying to do MITM attack (very rare in these days)

How to fix it:

1. Remove saved information about raspberry pi host

```
sudo vim ~/.ssh/known_hosts
or
sudo vim /etc/ssh/known_hosts
```

2. Use ssh-keygen

```
ssh-keygen -R host_ip
or
ssh-keygen -R host_ip -f path_to_known_hosts
```

3. Remove known_hosts
   If you have only one host in "known_hosts" file you can just remove it.

```
sudo rm .ssh/known_hosts
```